# DropBox delegate methods not being called?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I want to show the upload process in DropBox. file is successfully uploaded with path. but the problem is that dropbox delegate methods are not calling.

```
[[self restClient] uploadFile:@"1.png" toPath:@"/" withParentRev:nil fromPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Default" ofType:@"png"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self restClient].delegate);


  - (DBRestClient *)restClient {
    if (!restClient) {
        restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
        restClient.delegate = self;
    }
    return restClient;
}
```

> Implemention of delegate methods

```
 - (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadProgress:(CGFloat)progress forFile:(NSString*)destPath;{

    NSLog(@"%f",progress);

}
```

Comment: And I'm assuming your NSLog does return the proper delegate object?

Comment: yes it is self.viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to see *upload* progress, right? If so, you need to implement `uploadProgress`, not `loadProgress`.